# IPMI Power Commands for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm in the process of developing an internal app for my team that allows them to power up systems remotely using the remote computer's IPMI interface. I noticed that there is a Linux command `ipmipower`, but I was trying to figure out if there is a Windows equivalent of said command?

UPDATE:

Below I provided an answer to my problem.

Comment: If that update solved your issue, edit it out of your question and add it as an answer below. Self-answering is encouraged here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a utility I'm going to test later today.

[ipmiutil](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/)

If you want to silently install this utility, you can use something very similar to the following script I wrote.

```
pushd "%~dp0"

cd ipmiutil-2.8.8-win64

REM Install impiutil
set MYBIN="C:\Program Files\IPMIUtil"
copy libeay32.dll    %SystemRoot%\system32
copy ssleay32.dll    %SystemRoot%\system32
copy showselmsg.dll  %SystemRoot%\system32
start showsel.reg
mkdir  %MYBIN%
copy *.exe  %MYBIN%
```

Once installed you can run the following command

```
impiutil reset -u -N node -U user -P/-R rmt_pswd
```